# Splitting C++ templates between two headers

Tags: c++, templates, split, header, between

I've tried splitting a template between two headers:

1.h

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        void RunFunc();
};
```

2.h

```
#include "1.h"
template <typename T>
void A::RunFunc()
{
    printf("Ran this function!\n");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "2.h"
int main()
{
    A<int> B;
    B.RunFunc();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And it doesn't work, I'm trying to understand why logically it won't link -> I mean header files are just being "dumped", so when it comes to templates, I can't make one header's code get dumped into the other header?

The error:

```
In file included from main.cpp
./2.h error: 'A' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
void A::RunFunc()
     ^
./1.h note: 'A' declared here
class A
```

NOTE: This is only for practice! I am not really gonna work with two headers, I am just trying to understand the compiler as best as possible. Treat this as a normal question even though in writing conventions this is bad!

EDIT:
I forgot to add on 2.h in the func call : A::RunFunc() a template parameter, so it didn't compile. Thanks a bunch for helping! It came out a dumb question after all :/

The fix:

2.h

```
#include "1.h"
template <typename T>
void A<T>::RunFunc()
{
    printf("Ran this function!\n");
}
```

Comment: You made `A` a class template instead of making `RunFunc` a template method.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I forgot to add the <T> on A<T>::RunFunc()!